# Can OpenProcess with error code ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED be used to know if process exists?

Tags: c++, winapi, access-denied, pid

I run the following code on a Windows platform. The purpose is the know if a specific process ID refers to an existing process.

```
BOOL bProcessExists = FALSE;
HANDLE hProcHandle = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwProcID);
if(hProcHandle)
{
    bProcessExists = TRUE;
    ::CloseHandle(hProcHandle);
}
else
{
    if(::GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
    {
        bProcessExists = TRUE;
    }
}
```

The process that runs the code above does not run elevated and I found out that OpenProcess can return access denied for some process IDs.

Will the code above be valid?

Comment: Your code has a race condition: process IDs can be recycled. If you got the ID for "foo.exe" process, your code might report the process exists because now "bar.exe" has that ID (given foo.exe died). So it will tell you if there's _any_ process with that ID, but without further verification, what good is that for?

Comment: Good point. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be more worried about your assumption that being able to open the process means the process exists (except for extremely loose definitions of "exists").

An *entry* for the process will be retained as long as there's at least one handle to that process open. If (for example) a parent spawns a process, then keeps a handle to the child process, there will still be an entry for the child process, even after that process has exited. In that situation, assuming you have the proper rights, you'll be able to open a handle to the process, even though the process has already exited.

To handle this case correctly, you probably want to call `GetExitCodeProcess`, and only say the process exists if that returns `STILL_ALIVE` as the process' status.

As for the other part, I can't say with certainty that it'll work, but I'd say there's a good chance. I've used a similar technique for verifying users' passwords -- have them enter a proposed user-name and password. Then use `NetUserChangePassword` (with *out* the right to change the password). Then you look at the error you get -- `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` means the user-name/password combo they entered was valid, and `ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD` means it wasn't valid.

Comment: OK. I see. It is not as simple as it sounds :) Thanks for the info.