# Judging if a process exists by pid windows

Tags: c++, winapi, access-denied

The original goal of the function that I'm developing was to, simply, check if a process still exists(not terminated, fully running) in Windows platform given a specific process ID. However, I was met with a strange situation where `OpenProcess()` was returning `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (Code:5) although no such process was showing on the Process Explorer.

So I searched, and found a similar question that shared some ideas on what I was looking for.

[Can OpenProcess with error code ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED be used to know if process exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279035/can-openprocess-with-error-code-error-access-denied-be-used-to-know-if-process-e)

I was able to identify the problem, but since the solution did not shine much light on handling `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` side of the process.

Anyhow, I got some ideas out of the question. And Here's the code I've got so far

```
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwPid);

    if( hProcess == NULL )
    {
        dwLastError = GetLastError();
        if( dwLastError == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED )
        {
            HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
            PROCESSENTRY32 processEntry;
            processEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
            if (Process32First(hSnap, &processEntry))
            {
                while( Process32Next(hSnap, &processEntry) )
                {
                    if (processEntry.th32ProcessID == dwPid)
                    {
                        bAliveProcess = TRUE;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            CloseHandle(hSnap);
        }

    }
    else 
    {
        BOOL bExit = GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, &dwExitCode);
        if (dwExitCode == STILL_ACTIVE)
        {
            bAliveProcess = TRUE;
        }
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
```

With the code above, I was able to filter out the problem I described earlier. But I just feel like iterating entire process list seems like a big overhead if it gets called constantly. Would there be a better method on approaching this type of problem? Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

*Edit:*
I understand there is a case where **a process is not running, but its object still exists** (such case may be, a caller did not close the process handle). I did not want to count such cases as *process existing* since they are not actually running. That's why I used `GetExitCodeProcess()` for the processes that I have the access rights and `tl32Snapshot` for the process that I don't.
Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: This doesn't address your issue, but you are ignoring the 1st `processEntry` returned by `Process32First()`, you should be using a `do..while` loop instead of a `while` loop. Also, a process that is still present (because there are open handles to it) but not actually alive will appear in an enumeration of processes, so that doesn't tell you anything about the state of the process ID you find. And FYI, `EnumProcesses()` would be more lightweight than `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`

Comment: `OpenProcess()` may be failing because of your process does not have the required rights. For example, the process you are trying to open may be running in admin mode and yours isn't

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay, here's my logic behind. I thought when I call `OpenProcess()` and receive `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` would be my first condition for checking the existence of a process. But there could be processes that have higher access rights and be not really executing (like you mentioned). That's why I chose to enumerate the processes to filter. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Lokeshm27  In my full code, I call a process with higher to perform the same. The problem I want to solve is when the process that I'm querying has `System` access right, and when they are dangling (alive but not doing anything).

Comment: if you got access denied (more accurate will be check last ntstatus via `RtlGetLastNtStatus()`) this mean that process object exist

Comment: but *process still exists(which means fully running)* - this is wrong. process can already terminated, but process object still exist

Comment: `GetExitCodeProcess` also not correct way detect are process not terminated - this of course very rarely but process can exit with code `STILL_ACTIVE`. correct - call `WaitForSingleObject` on process handle (you need ask access`SYNCHRONIZE` on process)

Comment: @RbMm Okay, I think I'm loosing a track here. Does a terminated process (with the object alive) matter? I assumed those kind of processes rarely come up in the system. I may have phrased the question wrong. I'll be more clear.

Comment: from where you got process pid and unclear what is your final target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would there be a better method on approaching this type of problem?

Indeed so.

**Using PID for checking if process is alive is not a solution** - so you should go back and check your overall design.

Just use the handle you get when the process is started:

`HANDLE hProcess = CreateProcess(...`

It could sound like the process is not created from this process - so perhaps obtain it like you do once, and keep it (ie. try to store the handle once the process is found instead of keep using the PID).

Now you can check using for example the function `GetExitCodeProcess` ala.:

```
  DWORD returnCode{};
  if (GetExitCodeProcess(handle, &returnCode)) {
    if (returnCode != STILL_ACTIVE) {
      //no longer active
```

The reason using PID is bad is twofold: the OS may keep the process in a *dead* state for a while *and* the PID may already be reused for a new process once you check it (you simply cannot control that in any normal cases).

As for the `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`: it's not a reliable method *at all* to check if the process exists or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You mentioned exactly what I was concerned about. I'm already having issues & bugs about reused PIDs. From what I understand of your comment, you are recommending to pass around the process handle from the beginning to end, am I right? And about the use of `GetExitCodeProcess`, does it detect a process that are in a dead state?

Comment: no, if we got `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` - this is 100% say about process object with same pid exist. another way - we can not say in what it state

Comment: @vaska11 yes and yes

Comment: GetExitCodeProcess is not good for this purpose. Read the docs: Important  The GetExitCodeProcess function returns a valid error code defined by the application only after the thread terminates. Therefore, an application should not use STILL_ACTIVE (259) as an error code. If a thread returns STILL_ACTIVE (259) as an error code, applications that test for this value could interpret it to mean that the thread is still running and continue to test for the completion of the thread after the thread has terminated, which could put the application into an infinite loop.

Comment: @NorbertBoros correct - if you are dealing with unknown processes that might return arbitrary codes, then using this method is not 100% sure thing.